# Ray and surface intersection

Tags: matlab, graphics, scanning

I'm rather new to Matlab and perhaps this problem isn't difficult, yet I'm having problems. My code looks like this

```
x=-25:0.1:25; y=-25:0.1:25; [X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
R=sqrt(X.^2+Y.^2);
Z=sin(R);

faces=delaunay(X,Y);
alpha(0.3);
trisurf(faces,X,Y,Z,'Edgecolor','none');
axis ([-20 20 -20 20 -1 51]);
axis equal;
xlabel('X');
ylabel('Y');
alpha(1);
hold on
syms t;
x_source=20;  
x_dir=-2;
y_source=0;   
y_dir=3;
z_source=50;  
z_dir=-10;

height_above_plane = @(t) z_source + t * z_dir - interp2(X, Y, Z, ...
    x_source + t*x_dir, y_source + t*y_dir);
t_intercept = fzero(height_above_plane, 0)

x_ray = x_source + t_intercept * x_dir;
y_ray = y_source + t_intercept * y_dir;
z_ray = z_source + t_intercept * z_dir;
plot(x_ray,y_ray,'r.','MarkerSize',10);
```

As if the ray starts at a position 20;0;50. What I'm trying to make is a virtual laser scan procedure. fzero gives me a NaN, when x_dir exceeds a small number and I can't figure out why... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The bad cycle after solving the problem:

```
t=0;
x_source=20;
y_source=0;
z_source=50;
z_dir=-10;
for alfa=26:0.5:6
 x_dir=tand(alfa)*z_dir;
    for beta=16:0.5:-16
    y_dir=tand(beta)*z_dir;    
  y_dir=3;
    height_above_plane = @(t) z_source + t * z_dir - interp2(X, Y, Z, ...
    x_source + t*x_dir, y_source + t*y_dir,'linear',0);
    t_intercept = fmincon(@(t) abs(height_above_plane(t)),0,[],[],[],[],4.5,6)

    x_ray = x_source + t_intercept * x_dir;
    y_ray = y_source + t_intercept * y_dir;
    z_ray = z_source + t_intercept * z_dir;
    plot(x_ray,y_ray,'k.','MarkerSize', 20);
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full error is

```
Exiting fzero: aborting search for an interval containing a sign change
    because NaN or Inf function value encountered during search.
(Function value at -2.56 is NaN.)
Check function or try again with a different starting value.
```

and your function evaluated at -2.56 does indeed return `NaN`. This is because your are doing `interp2(X,Y,Z,x_source + t*x_dir, y_source + t*y_dir)` but `x_source-2.56*x_dir=25.12`. Since your data is only for `x` between -25 and 25, you have to extrapolate to get the interpolant here. By default, Matlab returns `NaN` for extrapolation, but you can change the value using the optional fifth argument to `interp2`, `EXTRAPVAL` (add `,'linear',0` to the `interp2` call, check the documentation (0 might not be a good choice either)).

Given you want constrained root solving, consider using `fmincon` instead, like this:

```
t_intercept = fmincon(@(t) abs(height_above_plane(t)),0,[],[],[],[],-2.5,25/3)
```

which is slower, but more robust, as long as you have a way of working out what the limits on `t` have to be.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! However my attempt to put this into a for cycle failed. It doesn't give me any kind of error though, so once again I don't know what to do.. I edited the original post to show the cycle

Comment: You will have to change 4.5 and 6 for each iteration I would imagine.

Comment: Oh, I thought that is the interval for my t variable. "solution is in the range of lb<= x <=ub" is what Matlab help says

Comment: Yes, it's the range for `t`, but the range for `t` is set by ensuring that `-25 < x_source + t*x_dir < 25` and likewise for `y_source`, so that you can do the interpolation. Maybe try `max((x_source-25)/x_dir,(y_source-25)/y_dir)` for the lower bound, and something similar (but with a `min`) for the upper bound.

Comment: With z_dir being a constant -10 and the min distance from source being 49.5 we know, that t will never be shorter than 4.5, but the funny thing is, not even a loop like | for blob = 45:0.5:5
    disp(blob)
end | in a separate script is working for me on matlab right now, perhaps it's time to go to sleep...

Comment: Thank you for your help!